# Show $e_k(X) = \frac{1}{k!} X(X − 1)⋯(X − k + 1)$ generates the $\mathbb{Z}$-module Int($\mathbb{Z}$)

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I want to show that $e_k(X) = \frac{1}{k!} X(X − 1)⋯(X − k + 1)$ (with $e_0$ = 1) is a basis for Int($\mathbb{Z}$). I have shown $\mathbb{Z}$-linear indepence, so I just need to show it generates Int($\mathbb{Z}$). My intuition tells me to use induction. The initial case is very simple, as every element of degree 0 from Int($\mathbb{Z}$) can be obtained as a multiple of $e_0$. But now I am stuck, how can I do the inductive step? Or is there any better ideas than using induction?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the difference $Q(x)=P(x+1)-P(x)$ and properties of binomial coefficients for a proof by induction on the degree that all $P \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ such that $P(\mathbb{Z})\subset \mathbb{Z}$ is a lineary combinaison of the $e_k$ with coefficient in $\mathbb{Z}$.

We have $\deg Q \lt \deg P$.

What is the sum $\sum_{i=0}^n e_k(i)$ ?

> $$e_{k+1}(n+1)$$

What do imply that two polynomes coincide on an infinite number of points ?

> $$\text{They are equal.}$$

Then using $P(n)-P(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} Q(i)$ you can show the result.

Comment: What is P? Can you elaborate it further?